# How to test mobile code remotely?

Tags: xcode, mobile

Not sure where this question should go.

If you have a remote machine that you develop on and the code must stay on that machine, how can you do mobile development?  In other words, how do you test your code if you can't plug a device into the machine?

This would be for native or web based mobile apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS and Android:

You could use remote access for the machine to do the actual development and then upload your build to testflight (https://www.testflightapp.com) and send the build to your device (which can download it as long as your on a wifi network etc.). Not the most elegant solution but may work depending on how often you want to build it on the device as opposed to the simulator.